# Delete duplicate records of dates in w weeks format for groups laravel

Tags: laravel

I hope someone can help me.

I have a schedule in Laravel that should perform this function: in practice it must find in the db the duplicate records on dates in week format, so for example week 48 week 48 etc.. in the db there are the normal dates written in current timestamp but in the view thanks to the carbon::parse() method I display them in week format.

My function should find duplicates for groups of people etc. and should delete the duplicate week records of the groups

I wrote this little function but I'm not able to go further because I don't understand where I'm going wrong. thanks a lot in advance this is my code..

```
   $result = EsitiAudit::where('frequency_audit', 'WEEK')
        ->groupBy(['master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea', 'frequency_audit', 'data_audit', 'esito', 'employee', 'eseg_riass', 'categoria'])
        ->get();

        foreach ($result as $item) {
            $init[] = [
                'id' => $item->id,
                'data' => Carbon::parse($item->data_audit)->format('W')
            ];
        }

        $ids = $init->pluck('id')->toArray();

        EsitiAudit::whereNotIn('id', $ids)->delete();

        return dd('ok');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ9Gy.png)

db example in screenshot record 9 and 12 are part of the same group and have the same week even if the dates are different

this is why record 12 should be removed

the function should find the records for groups for example week 48 week 48 etc. of a specific group of things and people and eliminate the duplicate so that only one remains